# discord.py mute command not adding roles

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.User,time,*,reason):
    if user:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute"):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute")

            addroles = []

            for i in user.roles:
                try:
                    await user.remove_roles(i)
                    addroles.append(i.id)
                except:
                    print(f"Can't remove the role {i}")
            await user.add_roles(role)
            
            cmd_used("mute",ctx.author,ctx.message.content)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"""{bot.user.name}""",colour=maincolor)
            embed.add_field(name=f"""`{ctx.author}` muted you from `{user.guild.name}`""",value=f"""time: {time}s, reason: {reason}""",inline=True)
            await user.send(embed=embed)

            await asyncio.sleep(int(time))
            await user.remove_roles(role)
            print(addroles)
            await user.add_roles(addroles)

#errors: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

basically my mute command literally isn't working cause it mutes them and doesn't give their old roles back.
i need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addroles` is in your case a list of the role ids the user had before the command. However [`add_roles(role)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) takes a role as argument, not a list of role ids.

---

You can either just save the actual role object in `addroles`, iterate over that list and assign them

```
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.User,time,*,reason):
    if user:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute"):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute")

            addroles = []

            for i in user.roles:
                try:
                    await user.remove_roles(i)
                    addroles.append(i)
                except:
                    print(f"Can't remove the role {i}")
            await user.add_roles(role)
            
            cmd_used("mute",ctx.author,ctx.message.content)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"""{bot.user.name}""",colour=maincolor)
            embed.add_field(name=f"""`{ctx.author}` muted you from `{user.guild.name}`""",value=f"""time: {time}s, reason: {reason}""",inline=True)
            await user.send(embed=embed)

            await asyncio.sleep(int(time))
            await user.remove_roles(role)
            print(addroles)

            for role in addroles:
                await user.add_roles(role)
```

---

Or a far better approach would be to use [`discord.Member.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.edit), because it only sends one request to the Discord API.

For example, you can remove **all** roles of a user with the command

```
await user.edit(roles = [])
```

As you can see, this is far more efficient, and should be the preferred solution

```
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.User,time,*,reason):
    if user:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute"):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="mute")

            addroles = user.roles

            await user.edit(roles = [role]) # remove all roles and only give the user the mute-role
            
            cmd_used("mute",ctx.author,ctx.message.content)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=f"""{bot.user.name}""",colour=maincolor)
            embed.add_field(name=f"""`{ctx.author}` muted you from `{user.guild.name}`""",value=f"""time: {time}s, reason: {reason}""",inline=True)
            await user.send(embed=embed)

            await asyncio.sleep(int(time))
            await user.edit(roles = addroles) # gives old roles back, overwrites the mute role
```